# How to move content of removable drive to folder on the same drive using CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I want to move all the content (including sub-folders) of a removable drive to folder which is inside the drive.

This is how it looks in Windows Explorer:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FVIN.png]

Comment: this website 'SS64' http://ss64.com/ will help or is a good reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I move content (including sub-folders) of a drive to a different folder

Use the following batch file (MoveContent.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem create target folder
md "Target Folder"
rem use dir to get a list of file and folders
rem use findstr /v to exclude target folder from the list
rem use for to loop through the list
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b ^| findstr /v "Target Folder"` ) do (
  rem move the items in the list
  move "%%i" "Target Folder"
)
endlocal
```

Note:

- This will move the batch file as well to `Target Folder`.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [move](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) - Move a file from one folder to another.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne 'Target folder'} | Move-Item -Destination 'Target folder'
```

The first command in the pipeline (`Get-ChildItem`) gets all the entries in the current folder. The second filters by name, passing everything to the next command except items named `Target folder`. That final command moves the item (whether it be a file or folder) into the target folder.

Compact version:

```
$t='Target folder';gci|?{$_.Name -ne $t}|mv -Dest $t
```

Script (`.ps1`) version, see [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info) for instructions on enabling scripts:

```
$target = $args[0]
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne $target} | Move-Item -Destination $target
```

You would then invoke that script with the destination folder as the only argument.

To run a PowerShell command from a normal command prompt, type `powershell -command` followed by anything you could put at a PowerShell prompt, enclosed in quotes:

```
powershell -command "$t='Target folder';gci|?{$_.Name -ne $t}|mv -Dest $t"
```

Comment: Simples compared to the cmd solution :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the contents of removeable driver to another folder on the same removeable drive DOS has the **move** command.

say r: is the drive letter.

```
r:\>md everything
r:\>move *.* everything
```

Comment: thanks, but only the files moved and not the folders on the drive.

Comment: @IlayCaliv Just add an additional command as `r:\> MOVE /Y "<DirToMove>" "<DirToMoveTo>"` and it will move the folder(s) you specify as well. The `MOVE *.*` will move only the files so you need to specify to move the directories where applicable too. You can run `MOVE /?` to get further detail on the syntax and switches.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT See my answer for a more elegant solution requiring only one call to `move`

Comment: @DavidPostill Looks good David as usual with your work!!